# Is "the president's campaign" an equivalent of "the presidential election campaign"?

Tags: word-meaning

I mean, on most occasions, does "the president's campaign" mean a "presidential election process"?

Comment: Your title does not match the examples in your question (process vs. campaign)? I'm confused.

Comment: @user3169 Maybe I misused the word "process" in my post. The doubtful point should be if there is any difference between "the president's campaign" and "the presidential election campaign".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "campaign" is not the electoral process but a strenuous and systematic effort to promote some particular goal.

- The original sense of *campaign* was “countryside, open country”; the contemporary sense derives from military usage. Down to the 19th century armies customarily spent the winter in camp or (if they could capture one) in a city; when the weather grew warm again they ‘took the field’, marched out into open country to pursue military objectives. *Campaign* thus came to denote one year’s activity in the field. Eventually the idiom was extended, metaphorically, to any sustained effort toward a specific goal in politics, advertising or public relations.

"The president's campaign" is thus not the process of electing a president or any individual's effort to be elected president, but a campaign for some goal conducted by the president.

Often the president's campaign is his campaign for re-election ... but a president campaigns for lots of other things, too: for passage of a particular law, for public  support of this or that policy, for election of other members of his party, or for something quite abstract such as a change of priorities or renewed attention to a matter in which he is interested.